# Exempt the order from tax (except woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to exempt the order from tax. It is necessary that "set_is_vat_exempt" occurs during checkout and acts on the current order, and not only on subsequent ones. This cannot be done via "init".
I would be grateful if someone tells me a hook or another solution that can replace init (except woocommerce_checkout_update_order_review).

```
add_action( 'init', 'wc_tax_exempt' );
function wc_tax_exempt_unlogged() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(FALSE);
    $cur_user_id = get_current_user_id();
    $tax_exempt = get_user_meta( $cur_user_id, 'tax_exempt', true );
    if( $tax_exempt == 1){
        $woocommerce->customer->set_is_vat_exempt(true);  
    }
}
```

Comment: Setup your taxes in your store. Exclude products from tax with tax rates. No need of custom stuff. Read more about here - https://woocommerce.com/document/setting-up-taxes-in-woocommerce/ If you insist on going your path try - woocommerce_before_calculate_totals